# Deployment From one Dev org to another Dev Org

Tags: deployment, change-set

is it possible to deploy the classes and respected test classes one dev org to another dev org using Change-Set.

Comment: No you can not do that with changeset. Use ANT/Eclipse instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From documentation:-

> You can move metadata only between the production org and its
>   sandboxes. You can’t move changes between two production orgs or
>   Developer Editions.

You can take advantage of ANT or Eclipse Force.com ide instead.

Can have look into this link for more info. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/alm_deployment/alm_tools

Comment: And Packages, too.

Comment: The force.com workbench is also quite easy to use https://workbench.developerforce.com/